# Asynchronous MVC controller action method execution not waiting at 'await'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I am using MVC 4 along with .NET 4.5. I wish to build an asynchronous controller leveraging the new TAP (async await). I have inherited this controller from `Controller` and not `AsyncContoller`, since I am using task-based asynchronicity, not event-based asynchronicity.

I have two action methods - one to perform an operation synchronously, and another to perform the same operation asynchronously. I also have two submit buttons in the form in my View, one for each action method.

Here is the code for both the methods:

Synchronous:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexSync(FormCollection formValues)
{
        int Min = Int32.Parse(formValues["txtMin"]);
        int Count = Int32.Parse(formValues["txtCount"]);
        string Primes;
        DateTime started = DateTime.Now;
        using (BackendServiceReference.ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient())
        {
            Primes = service.GetPrimesServiceMethod(Min, Count);
        }
        DateTime ended = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan serviceTime = ended - started;
        ViewBag.ServiceTime = serviceTime;
        ViewBag.Primes = Primes;

        return View("Index");
}
```

Asynchronous:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(FormCollection formValues)
{
        int Min = Int32.Parse(formValues["txtMin"]);
        int Count = Int32.Parse(formValues["txtCount"]);
        string Primes;
        Task<string> PrimesTask;
        DateTime started = DateTime.Now;
        using (BackendServiceReference.ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient())
        {
            PrimesTask = service.GetPrimesServiceMethodAsync(Min, Count);
        }
        DateTime ended = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan serviceTime = ended - started;
        ViewBag.ServiceTime = serviceTime;
        Primes = await PrimesTask;
        ViewBag.Primes = Primes;

        return View("Index");
}
```

In the async method, I expect `DateTime ended = DateTime.Now` to execute immediately after the service method is called, while the time-consuming service method executes asynchronously in the background.

However, this does not happen, and the execution 'waits' when the service method is called, instead of waiting where `Primes = await PrimesTask` happens.

Is there anything I have missed?

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Your async call is made when you call "Primes = await PrimesTask;" - not in the using AFAIK

Comment: @MichaelSkarum Debugging using breakpoints, I found that the execution 'waits' at `PrimesTask = service.GetPrimesServiceMethodAsync(Min, Count)`. Why is it so? Shouldn't it wait at `Primes = await PrimesTask`?

Comment: What's inside of GetPrimesServiceMethodAsync? You are probably blocking there. Note, that await does not start a new thread (many people assume that).

Comment: @usr I have a straightforward synchronous method `GetPrimesServiceMethod` (returns `string`) defined in a WCF service. `GetPrimesServiceMethodAsync` (returns `Task<string>`) is a proxy method generated for consumption on the client side by WCF.

Comment: Should be ok then. Pause the debugger during the wait. Look at the callstack (including external code). This will tell us what is running there and hint at *why*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that it is actually blocking in `ServiceClient.Dispose`.

To resolve this, extend the `using` block to include your `await`:

```
using (BackendServiceReference.ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient())
{
    PrimesTask = service.GetPrimesServiceMethodAsync(Min, Count);
    DateTime ended = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan serviceTime = ended - started;
    ViewBag.ServiceTime = serviceTime;
    Primes = await PrimesTask;
}
ViewBag.Primes = Primes;
```

Comment: I suspect this as well :) Reminds me of your article on Dispose in combination with async work.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary! That solved my problem! Would love to read more about it though. Any links?

Comment: I'm not aware of any documentation on this in particular. Just keep in mind that `GetPrimesServiceMethodAsync` was *still running* when you disposed its instance, and that's just not a good idea. :)

Comment: In retrospect, it seems like such a silly mistake. Anyway, thanks again!